# Get-PnPSearchConfiguration returns only one vaiue SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell

I am attempting to export the definition of all managed properties for am online site collection.  The connection to the site works find and `SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline` returns an object, but it contains only one value.  The `CompleteXML` option also return only one result.

FWIW, the Admin ran the export option for in the Admin Center and as expected on the Subscript level properties appeared , and in `CompleteXML` format.

Here is what I ran and the results:
The code is pretty much a single line

Connect-PnPOnline -Url *$web* -Credentials *$mycreds*

$ssa = Get-PnPSearchConfiguration -Scope *Site* -OutputFormat *ManagedPropertyMappings*

Write-Host $ssa

**Name            Aliases Mappings Type**
RefinableString10 {TitleRS} {Title} Text

Comment: could you provide your code? I will test it in my environment.

Comment: The code is pretty much a single line  

Connect-PnPOnline _Url *$web* -Credentials *$mycreds*  

$ssa = Get-PnPSearchConfiguration -Scope *Site* -OutputFormat *ManagedPropertyMappings*  

Write-Host $ssa

## Name Aliases Mappings Type ##
RefinableString10 {TitleRS} {Title} Text

Answer (score 1):

```
Get-PnPSearchConfiguration -Scope Site -OutputFormat ManagedPropertyMappings
```

The cmdlet is used to return all **custom** managed properties and crawled property mapping at the **current site collection**

So, check the custom managed properties and crawled property mapping at your site collection via UI to find if there are only one value matched.

Comment: Kally,  does **custom** managed properties mean that the Refinable managed properties are excluded (there or 35 of them in the site I'm testing)?  If so, is there another technique to obtain this information without going through the UI?

Comment: I ran a few extra tests.  The cmdlet provides the correct result connected to an On-prem site.  I also had an Admin run the cmdlet on the SPO site, with the same results.